# How to do array addition multiplication program in a shell script?

Tags: linux, array

Write a program arr_calc to perform array addition and array multiplication,
The program takes 4 arguments:

Argument 1: The file name of the input array A
Argument 2: The file name of the input array B
Argument 3: The file name of the output array C
Argument 4: The calculation (a for addition, m for multiplication)

e.g., arr_calc file1 file2 file3 a

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? There is no such thing as multiplication of arrays (or if you prefer, there are many different concepts that could be called multiplication of arrays, so you need to say which one you mean). If don't manage to give a precise description, at least give an example! If you want to do matrix operations, the shell is not a good language.

Answer (score 3):

using shell Programming:
This is a shell script to adding matrices with each other:

```
#!/bin/bash 

read -p "Enter the matrix order [mxn] : " t 
m=${t:0:1} 
n=${t:2:1} 

echo "Enter the elements for first matrix" 
for i in `seq 0 $(($m-1))` 
do 
for j in `seq 0 $(($n-1))` 
 do 
     read x[$(($n*$i+$j))] 
done 
done 

echo "Enter the elements for second matrix" 
for i in `seq 0 $(($m-1))` 
do 
for j in `seq 0 $(($n-1))` 
do 
    read y[$(($n*$i+$j))] 
    z[$(($n*$i+$j))]=$((${x[$(($n*$i+$j))]}+${y[$(($n*$i+$j))]})) 
done 
done 

echo "Matrix after addition is"  
for i in `seq 0 $(($m-1))` 
do 
for j in `seq 0 $(($n-1))` 
do 
    echo -ne "${z[$(($n*$i+$j))]}\t" 
done 
echo -e "\n" 
done 

exit 0
```

for matrices Multiplication, you can use the same logic above.